# create-react-app not working not after upgrading npm and nodejs

Tags: create-react-app

I upgraded npm and nodejs to 6.14.4 and 12.16.3 resp. Getting below error while creating react app using `create-react-app`.

[image: create-react-app not working]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [readme](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app):

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via `npm
>   install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package
>   using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` to ensure that npx always uses
>   the latest version.

So resolved the problem using command:
`npx create-react-app contactmanager`